# FastReport( vs C#) with LPT1 ZPL printer (Zebra ZM 400)

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, fastreport, zpl

i'm using fastreport and ZPL printer. i designed my report with barcode and try to print from ZPL (Zebra ZM400) printer. it's decreasing darkness 15. i set it 30. print the document again and sender decreased it 15 again. so dont print anything. label is out but nothing on it,it is null. Anyone help ?

i solved this problem. Changed darkness on printer settings on windows.
my new question is how can i send print without driver on LPT1 port ?

Comment: Kindly Edit (Format) your question

Comment: I've used the raw printer helper.  This questions is similar [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669403/how-to-send-a-raw-zpl-to-zebra-printer-using-c-sharp-via-usb][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669403/how-to-send-a-raw-zpl-to-zebra-printer-using-c-sharp-via-usb